# Where is the search field on twitter.com?

Tags: twitter, search

I'm not a user of Twitter, and I have no intention to create an account there. There is no search box on Twitter’s [landing page](http://twitter.com).

What path should I follow to get to a page where I can search amongst other people’s tweets?

When I reach a page on twitter.com, there is a search box on top.

Comment: Twitter only displays the search box once your signed in. As Alex pointed out below you can follow that URL to the search page. Alternatively you could just use Google as well and site:twitter.com at the end of your query.

Answer (score 5):

The search page can be found here: https://twitter.com/search-home

Comment: I can't find the link to this page on www.twitter.com

Comment: @Antoine you're not making any sense. Why would Twitter place a search field on a sign up page.

Comment: @Antoine It isn’t one. `http://search.twitter.com/` leads to the URL above.

Comment: @phwd To allow me to do a search without signing up.

Comment: @Antoine It's a sign up page not a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the search within Twitter if you're logged in. If you don't want to register an account you'll need to use a different method. Most search engines let you limit your search to a particular site. Google and Bing use this syntax:

```
site:twitter.com "search terms"
```